# "more than one instance of overloaded function "std::pow" matches the argument list"

Tags: c++, namespaces, constants, c-preprocessor

With C++, I try to

```
#define TINY std::pow(10,-10)
```

I give the code with the `#include` and namespace information for the class (.h) where TINY is defined

```
#pragma once
#include "MMath.h"
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define TINY std::pow(10,-10)
```

I use TINY in some function implementation in .cpp file, and TINY gives error

> IntelliSense: more than one instance of overloaded function "std::pow" matches the argument list

What is right syntax?

Comment: the question title is very misleading since it has absolutely nothing to do with the preprocessor. Why are you using pow, instead of just writing 1e-10 ?

Comment: try std::pow(10.0, 10.0) to explicitly select the float/double overloads.

Comment: +1 for PlasmaHH: Using `const double tiny = 1E-10;` is by far the best and most-C++ solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:** I do agree with the commenters saying that using std::pow() in place of a literal constant is unnecessary - so for this particular problem, go with the `1.0E-10` constant; my explanation of the actual error you were getting and the way to solve it still stands.

This has nothing to do with your `#define`. `std::pow()` is an overloaded function, and none of its overloads take `(int, int)` as arguments. You should provide arguments with types which unambiguously select an overload. Depending on the type of return value you want, you'll probably want to select one of these overloads:

```
      float pow (       float base,       float exponent );
     double pow (      double base,         int exponent );
long double pow ( long double base,         int exponent );
```

which you can invoke as follows:

```
std::pow(10.0f, -10.0f)
std::pow(10.0, -10)
std::pow(10.0L, -10)
```

respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to define a constant variable and initialize it without using the `pow` function, like this

```
const double TINY = 1E-10; //1e-10 is 10 to the power of -10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `std::pow(10.0,-10.0)` instead: `std::pow` has multiple [overloads](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/) matching your argument list; specifying `10.0,-10.0` forces the use of the specific overload:

```
double pow(double base, double exponent);
```

Note that this `#define` may be suboptimal depending on the use of `TINY`: every time you use it in your code, a call will be made to `std::pow` to calculate the same value. A better approach would be to use a static variable, set it once, and use it from that point on.